# Calculated Date Column - Multiple IF and more

Tags: calculated-column

I've been trying to work this out for 2 days and I'm probably overcomplicating this but here's what I'd like to do.

If the employee has been employed >= 2 years they only need to take certain classes annually, and one class every three years. If employed less than 2 years, one of the courses is annual instead.

**Hired** is a date column. **Courses** is a choice column of class options. **Last Taken** is the date the course was last taken. The calculated column **Next Due**, showing the next due date after inputting the class and date the employee took it. I did have minor success with IF(OR but not having success with the below. I tried to figure it out in Excel but I'm unable to build the formula there.
**Today** is a column for the current date. I can either use a workflow to update daily or I can delete it after getting my formula right to trick SP (I've done both).

```
=IF(Today>=DATE(YEAR([Hired])+2,MONTH([Hired]),DAY([Hired])),
IF([Courses]="Class1",DATE(YEAR([Last Taken])+1,MONTH([Last Taken]),DAY([Last Taken]))),
IF([Courses]="Class2",DATE(YEAR([Last Taken])+1,MONTH([Last Taken]),DAY([Last Taken]))),
IF([Courses]="Class3",DATE(YEAR([Last Taken])+3,MONTH([Last Taken]),DAY([Last Taken]))))
```

The part below is if employed less than 2 years. It's just part of the code I lifted out of what I've been working on. I know the syntax is incorrect but no matter what I do (if I join them, use OR, use AND) it's just not working.

```
IF([Courses]="Class1",DATE(YEAR([Last Taken])+1,MONTH([Last Taken]),DAY([Last Taken]))),
IF([Courses]="Class2",DATE(YEAR([Last Taken])+1,MONTH([Last Taken]),DAY([Last Taken]))),
IF([Courses]="Class3",DATE(YEAR([Last Taken])+1,MONTH([Last Taken]),DAY([Last Taken]))))
```

I don't know how to get it all to work. And I do use Notepad++ and check my brackets but it's fruitless. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Edited to add this new section

```
=IF(Today() >= DATE(YEAR([Hired])+2,MONTH([Hired]),DAY([Hired])),
IF([Courses]="Class1",DATE(YEAR([Last Taken])+1,MONTH([Last Taken]),DAY([Last Taken])),
IF([Courses]="Class2",DATE(YEAR([Last Taken])+1,MONTH([Last Taken]),DAY([Last Taken])),
IF([Courses]="Class3",DATE(YEAR([Last Taken])+3,MONTH([Last Taken]),DAY([Last Taken])),"")))),
//need this section also - how to integrate with above?
IF(Today() <= DATE(YEAR([Hired])+2,MONTH([Hired]),DAY([Hired])),
IF([Courses]="Class1",DATE(YEAR([Last Taken])+1,MONTH([Last Taken]),DAY([Last Taken])),
IF([Courses]="Class2",DATE(YEAR([Last Taken])+1,MONTH([Last Taken]),DAY([Last Taken])),
IF([Courses]="Class3",DATE(YEAR([Last Taken])+1,MONTH([Last Taken]),DAY([Last Taken])),""))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had added the conditions in a wrong way. IF(condition, success, fail). Here is the correct way of your formula.

```
=IF(Today() >= DATE(YEAR([Hired])+2,MONTH([Hired]),DAY([Hired])),
IF([Courses]="Class1",DATE(YEAR([Last Taken])+1,MONTH([Last Taken]),DAY([Last Taken])),
IF([Courses]="Class2",DATE(YEAR([Last Taken])+1,MONTH([Last Taken]),DAY([Last Taken])),
IF([Courses]="Class3",DATE(YEAR([Last Taken])+3,MONTH([Last Taken]),DAY([Last Taken])),""))))
```

Note: I did not change any condition to check your requirement. Just corrected the formatting of your formula.

As I see your updated requirement, only 1 condition is needed to check if the date hired date is older than 2 years and assigning next due as year+3. Rest all have Year+1. SO here is the formula you should use.

```
=IF(AND(TODAY()>=DATE(YEAR([Hired])+2,MONTH([Hired]),DAY([Hired])),[Courses]="Class3"),
DATE(YEAR([Last Taken])+3,MONTH([Last Taken]),DAY([Last Taken])),
DATE(YEAR([Last Taken])+1,MONTH([Last Taken]),DAY([Last Taken])))
```

Formula is tested so it should not give you invalid formula error.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I get an error with that also.

Comment: I tested this formula. Are u getting invalid formula error? Did you rename column with your names?

Comment: My fault, so sorry! Yes, that works perfectly, thank you. Any suggestions on how would I add the last part to the code that (else) if hired date is less that two years?

Comment: The first condition in the above formula is today >= date hired+2 right. So that actually means hired date is less than 2 years.

Comment: So I have my greater than and less than confused? OK. Then how would I add in an else that says if employed greater than 2 years? I need both.

Comment: Add your exact requirement in question in simple coded if else statements. We can convert it into formula

Comment: Will have to do that above - which is what I thought I did initially?

Comment: Its not understandable. Please simplify it something like this- if a=b then date, else if a=c then date, else thisDate

Comment: I added it above - see bottom of original post. Is that any better?

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: Thank you. You've worked hard at trying to help me and I'm still having issues. I think this is too complex for me. I am still working on it but can't figure out how to integrate both codes. Each work separately but putting together does not. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You can try explaining the conditions in a better way rather. I made a formula based on your formula. You can clearly see there that you entered same Date(year+1,month,day) for all conditions except one. When you add formula check your that column name should be [hired]

Comment: Your code worked! Don't know why it didn't work yesterday but it was a long day and sometimes you just need to step back. Thank you! Also, I just learned (though you've been telling me this) that the Today function works in a calculated field. I was under the impression that it didn't and think that was part of the confusion! Thanks again!